# What are the available automatic failover solutions for MariaDB Master-Slave replication on Windows Server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, windows-server, high-availability, failover

I am setting up a **Master-Slave** or **Master-Master** setup in MariaDB on two seperate servers running **Windows Server**. I also need to configure an automatic failover solution where client read requests gets redirected to the slave in case the Master is down.

I am not familiar with MariaDB/MySQL but did a good amount of research online. However the solutions are all in Linux. i.e HeartBeat, Keepalive. I understand there is MariaDB MaxScale but Enterprise Subscription is currently not an option.

Can I please get a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Please maxscale or orchestrator to achieve this but for fail over you need at least three nodes to maintain quorum.